# How do you calculate return on investment for a share of stock?

Tags: investing, shares, rate-of-return

How do you calculate the return on investment for a single share of stock?  For example, what would be the return/value of a single Google share now, if bought in January 2015?

Answer (score 1):

To figure this out, you need to know the price per share then vs the price per share now.  Google Finance will show you historical prices.  For [GOOG](https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=304466804484872&startdate=Jan+3%2C+2015&enddate=Jan+2%2C+2016&num=30&ei=MC-IVpjLDsTWiwLCy43YAg), the closing price on January 5, 2015 was $513.87.  The price on December 31, 2015 was $758.88.  Return on Investment (ROI) is calculated with this formula:

ROI = (Proceeds from Investment - Cost of Investment) / Cost of Investment

Using this formula, your return on investment would be 47.7%.  Since the time period was one year, this number is already an annualized return.  If the time period was different than one year, you would normally [convert it to an annualized rate of return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return#Annualisation) in order to compare it to other investments.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included in your answer a company that paid a dividend, MO, for example.

Comment: If you have received any dividends from your stock, add those dividends into the numerator of the ROI formula.